# Is this PL/SQL Stored proc optimal?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```sql
create or replace procedure upsertTrackingItemMetric(
    p_template_id number,
    p_jobDef varchar2,
    p_metric_type varchar2,
    p_metric_value varchar2
)
is
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    sig_att_id number := null;
    sig_grp_id number := null;
    tims_id number := null;
    const_error_metric_id NUMBER := 3;
BEGIN

    select max(tims.ID) into tims_id
    from SREAPP.TRACKING_ITEM_METRIC_STORE tims
             join SREAPP.TRACKING_ITEM_METRIC_SIGNATURE_ATTRIBUTE sig_attrib
                  on tims.ID = sig_attrib.TRACKING_ITEM_METRIC_STORE_ID
             join SREAPP.ESSLOG_ERR_SIGNATURE sig on sig_attrib.value = to_char(sig.SIGNATURE_GROUPING_ID)
    where tims.signature_id = 7
      and tims.metric_id = 3
      and sig_attrib.signature_attribute_id = 13
      and sig.TEMPLATE_ID = p_template_id
      and tims.TRACKING_ITEM = p_metric_type
      and sig.JOB_DEFINITION = p_jobDef fetch first row only;


    if tims_id is null then
        insert into TRACKING_ITEM_METRIC_STORE (TRACKING_ITEM, METRIC_ID, SIGNATURE_ID, VALUE, ACTIVE)
        values(p_metric_type, const_error_metric_id, 7, p_metric_value,1)
        returning ID into tims_id;
    else
        UPDATE TRACKING_ITEM_METRIC_STORE SET VALUE = p_metric_value, ACTIVE = 1 where ID = tims_id;
    end if;

    select max(SIGNATURE_GROUPING_ID) into sig_grp_id
    from ESSLOG_ERR_SIGNATURE
    where JOB_DEFINITION = p_jobDef and TEMPLATE_ID = p_template_id fetch first row only;

    if sig_grp_id is null then

        -- first create the group
        INSERT INTO  ESSLOG_ERR_SIGNATURE_GROUP (NAME, DESCRIPTION)
            values(
                'create by ' || user || ' on ' || sysdate,
                p_template_id || '~' || p_jobDef
            )
        returning ID into sig_grp_id;
        -- Now tell the signature which group it belongs to
        insert into ESSLOG_ERR_SIGNATURE (SIGNATURE_GROUPING_ID,JOB_DEFINITION,TEMPLATE_ID)
            values (sig_grp_id,p_jobDef,p_template_id);
    end if;

    select max(SIGNATURE_ATTRIBUTE_ID) into sig_att_id from TRACKING_ITEM_METRIC_SIGNATURE_ATTRIBUTE
    where TRACKING_ITEM_METRIC_STORE_ID = tims_id
        and SIGNATURE_ATTRIBUTE_ID = 13
        and VALUE = to_char(sig_grp_id) fetch first row only;
    -- we only need to insert something if we had to create a group
    if sig_att_id is null then
        insert into TRACKING_ITEM_METRIC_SIGNATURE_ATTRIBUTE (TRACKING_ITEM_METRIC_STORE_ID, SIGNATURE_ATTRIBUTE_ID, VALUE)
            VALUES (tims_id, 13, to_char(sig_grp_id)) returning SIGNATURE_ATTRIBUTE_ID into sig_att_id;
    end if;

    commit;

END;
```

For example, I am taking advantage of the fact that `max` returns `null` on an empty set result.

Comment: Those hard-coded IDs (7, 3...) are a severe smell. Where do they come from? Why those IDs specifically?

Comment: In sane RDBMS this has [direct upsert support via `on conflict`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT). In Oracle, there's [UPSERT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/21.2/sqlfornosql/adding-table-rows-using-insert-and-upsert-statements.html).

Comment: In theory [MERGE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html) is a better way to go because it's SQL-standard. [Oracle also supports this.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F)

Comment: @Reinderien - upsert isn't supported on 19.x - sorry, I should have put that in the question

Comment: Yeah, they are from another table I didn't come up with - they're FKs without being FK constraints. My hands are tied there

Comment: `merge` is available all the way back in [12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F).

Comment: we were talking about upsert, not merge. Where would you suggest I use merge?

Comment: To replace the works. Merge is SQL-standard and can accomplish the same thing.

Comment: To help reviewers give you better answers, we need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*.  Please add sufficient context to your question to describe the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  Also, [edit] the **title** to simply [**summarise the task**](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Comment: Also, you haven't shown the definition of your tables and indexes as requested in the [tag:sql] tag wiki; without those it's hard to give a good review.  I recommend you include these definitions (preferably as SQL statements, so that reviewers can reproduce your test environment).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, consider `MERGE` to handle the conditional `INSERT` and `UPDATE` actions. Doing so, code arguably reads easier with three SQL statements and you avoid the procedural `IF/THEN/ELSE` statements and inserted variables. Because you do use some inserted variables in subsequent statements, you would need CTEs in the last `merge` which even necessitates a `group by` clause.

Additionally, consider a few other items:

- avoid mix cases such as camel casing in any object name including procedures;
- use a trigger for any action resulting from `INSERT` which avoids manually doing so in a separate procedure;
- not necessary but may help in readability, move some `WHERE` conditions to `ON` clauses especially with all inner joins;
- for aggregate queries without `GROUP BY`, `fetch first row only` may not be necessary;
- avoid hard-coded values for named variables to help in readability like the one declared constant you use since such constants may change in future as parameters.

```sql
create or replace procedure UPSERT_TRACKING_ITEM_METRIC(
    p_template_id number,
    p_jobDef varchar2,
    p_metric_type varchar2,
    p_metric_value varchar2
)
is
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    sig_att_id number := null;
    sig_grp_id number := null;
    tims_id number := null;
    const_error_metric_id NUMBER := 3;
BEGIN
    -- FIRST MERGE
    merge into TRACKING_ITEM_METRIC_STORE tgt
    using (
        select max(tims.ID) as max_tims_id
        from SREAPP.TRACKING_ITEM_METRIC_STORE tims
        join SREAPP.TRACKING_ITEM_METRIC_SIGNATURE_ATTRIBUTE sig_attrib
           on tims.ID = sig_attrib.TRACKING_ITEM_METRIC_STORE_ID
           and tims.signature_id = 7
           and tims.metric_id = 3
           and tims.TRACKING_ITEM = p_metric_type

        join SREAPP.ESSLOG_ERR_SIGNATURE sig 
           on sig_attrib.value = to_char(sig.SIGNATURE_GROUPING_ID)         
           and sig_attrib.signature_attribute_id = 13
           and sig.TEMPLATE_ID = p_template_id       
           and sig.JOB_DEFINITION = p_jobDef
     ) src

    on (src.max_tims_id = tgt.ID)

    when matched then
        update set tgt."VALUE" = p_metric_value, tgt.ACTIVE = 1 
        where tgt.ID = src.max_tims_id;

    when not matched then
        insert (tgt.TRACKING_ITEM, tgt.METRIC_ID, tgt.SIGNATURE_ID, tgt."VALUE", tgt.ACTIVE)
        values (p_metric_type, const_error_metric_id, 7, p_metric_value, 1);
        
    -- SECOND MERGE
    merge into ESSLOG_ERR_SIGNATURE_GROUP tgt
    using (
        select max(SIGNATURE_GROUPING_ID) as max_sig_grp_id
        from ESSLOG_ERR_SIGNATURE s
        where s.JOB_DEFINITION = p_jobDef 
          and s.TEMPLATE_ID = p_template_id
    ) src

    on (src.max_sig_grp_id = tgt.ID)

    when not matched
        insert (tgt."NAME", tgt.DESCRIPTION)
        values (
            'create by ' || user || ' on ' || sysdate,
            p_template_id || '~' || p_jobDef
        );

    -- THIRD MERGE
    merge into TRACKING_ITEM_METRIC_SIGNATURE_ATTRIBUTE tgt
    using (
        with sub_t as (
           select max(tims.ID) as max_tims_id
           from SREAPP.TRACKING_ITEM_METRIC_STORE tims
           join SREAPP.TRACKING_ITEM_METRIC_SIGNATURE_ATTRIBUTE sig_attrib
             on tims.ID = sig_attrib.TRACKING_ITEM_METRIC_STORE_ID
             and tims.signature_id = 7
             and tims.metric_id = 3
             and tims.TRACKING_ITEM = p_metric_type

           join SREAPP.ESSLOG_ERR_SIGNATURE sig 
             on sig_attrib.value = to_char(sig.SIGNATURE_GROUPING_ID)         
             and sig_attrib.signature_attribute_id = 13
             and sig.TEMPLATE_ID = p_template_id       
             and sig.JOB_DEFINITION = p_jobDef

        ), sub_e as (
           select max(SIGNATURE_GROUPING_ID) as max_sig_grp_id
           from ESSLOG_ERR_SIGNATURE s
           where s.JOB_DEFINITION = p_jobDef 
             and s.TEMPLATE_ID = p_template_id
       )

        select sub_t.max_tims_id, 
               to_char(sub_e.max_sig_grp_id) as max_sig_grp_id_char,
               max(main.SIGNATURE_ATTRIBUTE_ID) as max_sig_att_id 
        from TRACKING_ITEM_METRIC_SIGNATURE_ATTRIBUTE main
        join sub_t
          on main.TRACKING_ITEM_METRIC_STORE_ID = sub_t.max_tims_id
          and main.SIGNATURE_ATTRIBUTE_ID = 13
        join sub_e
          on main."VALUE" = to_char(sub_e.max_sig_grp_id)
        group by sub_t.max_tims_id,
                 to_char(sub_e.max_sig_grp_id)
    ) src

    on (
      src.max_sig_att_id = tgt.SIGNATURE_ATTRIBUTE_ID and 
      src.max_tims_id = tgt.TRACKING_ITEM_METRIC_STORE_ID and
      src.max_sig_grp_id_char = tgt."VALUE"
    )

    when not matched
       insert (tgt.TRACKING_ITEM_METRIC_STORE_ID, tgt.SIGNATURE_ATTRIBUTE_ID, tgt."VALUE")
       values (src.max_tims_id, 13, src.max_sig_grp_id_char);

    commit;

END;
```

Proposed Trigger:

```sql
create or replace trigger ESSLOG_ERR_SIGNATURE_GROUP_TRIGGER
    AFTER INSERT
    ON ESSLOG_ERR_SIGNATURE_GROUP
    FOR EACH ROW    
DECLARE
    p_template_id number;
    p_jobDef varchar2;
BEGIN
    -- SPLIT DESCRIPTION COLUMN BY ~ DELIMITER
    p_template_id := substr(:new.DESCRIPTION, 1, instr(:new.DESCRIPTION, '~', -1, 1) -1);
    p_jobDef := substr(:new.DESCRIPTION, instr(:new.DESCRIPTION, '~', -1, 1) +1);

    -- INSERT INTO RELATED TABLE   
    insert into ESSLOG_ERR_SIGNATURE (SIGNATURE_GROUPING_ID, JOB_DEFINITION, TEMPLATE_ID)
    values (:new.ID, p_jobDef, p_template_id);
END;
```

**Note**: Above refactoring has not been tested on actual data. Please take the time to solve issues and not expect a seamless answer. Slight adjustments may be needed.